# Geolocation IP in browser

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, yandex-maps

Who knows what hardware been using on PC (mac) for determining coordinates of the user? Many API use this case, but I want to know hardware details.

Comment: But services present separately IP based method and geolocation. Screen from yandex maps for example https://take.ms/Kcyxh

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: Common sources of location information include Global Positioning System (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input.